# g++ force debug info to be generated

Tags: c++, debugging, g++

I want to compile one line of code and generate debug info off of it -

```
int foo(int);
```

obviously you would not expect any debug info to be generated off of this, since it is not called anywhere and not defined, but I want to know if there are any options I can set to force information of this declaration to be generated never the less. I have tried to do `g++ -g -c -O0 foo.cpp`, but it isnt generating any information.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This really looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @nightcracker Because I need it... Im not planning to divulge my full project here. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas It is not. My question is how do I generate the debug info, I think I am clear on that. I added my attempt just as extra information; I am not asking why does my attempt not work.

Comment: @Dgrin91: No, you have a problem for which you believe the solution is to get debug information from that line. Your attempt is failing and you are asking the question. The question makes no sense, since the declaration won't even make it to the executable, there is nothing to debug in that line, there is no debug information. Or you could claim otherwise, the executable has all required information to debug that particular line of code even without the `-g` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function declarations don't even make it to the executable. That line is just for the compiler and does not have any generated code in the binary. Since it disappears during the compilation process there is no debug information that can be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Debug information is generated for function definitions, not declarations.  There is no point in generating debug information for a function declaration; such debug information would serve no purpose.

Type declarations may yield debug information, as this would help a debugger to locate the data members of objects of that type, but a free function declaration yields no useful debugging information.